# I got an error when downloading an image with picasso library

Tags: android, picasso

when I run this code on create method :

```
 Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(image);
```

I got this error :

```
     04-07 16:04:13.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1089): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 16:04:13.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1089): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
```

what is the problem ?

[image]

Comment: you should add it to the build path. What IDE are you using?

Comment: actually i add it to build path, i am using eclipse

Comment: already checked this? http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Comment: please see the picture that i add

Comment: This is not a Picasso issue. I recommend you use Android Studio and add Picasso into your `build.gradle` as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have two picasso jars? remove all of them. even right click on your project then Properties>Java Build Path>Libraries
and remove all jars from there too. 
then simply go to the directory in your pc that has the jar file and copy it and right click on the lib folder in your project and click paste. then clean your project, then it should be working.